# AsyncTask When server data changes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which sends HTTP get request to the server and gets a json string as the output. Currently, I run this periodically but I want to run it only when the server data changes. I think something like that can be down with SyncAdapter but it looks complicated and I don't want to send anything back to the server, I just want the results when the server data changes.

Comment: If you need to listen for the data changes from the server, you can implement a push to that server, if you own the server (you can use Firebase for this).

Comment: you should try using Sockets for this. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket

Comment: What have you tried. Please provide your coded attempt. Thanks

Comment: send push notification from the server to the app when data changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the back-end, you can try adding an implementation for sending a push notification. You can easily configure the payload of your push notification so that you can have have a specific push notification for each operation in your back-end.

Please see this example.

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Once you have a "send notification" function in your back-end system, you can call it after your data changes. Basically anytime a CRUD operation is made in your system use the push notification feature to notify your Android client.